# django ModelMultipleChoiceField queryset/filter for objects already associated

Tags: django, forms, filter, django-queryset

I have a Profile object with manytomany relationship to Category

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    . . . 
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
```

In my form, I want to display a checkbox of only the categories associated with the Profile
The code below will display all categories.

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    . . .
    category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Category.objects.all(),
                  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

How do i write a queryset so that I show only the categories associated with the Profile?
I've variations of this:

```
    category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Category.objects.filter(id__in=Profile.category.all()), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Has this error: 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: Nevermind:
I have to define the queryset in the view.  I gues sit has to do with run time variable

form.fields["category"].queryset = Category.objects.filter(profile=profile)

Answer (score 0):

woa this was asked 10 years ago..but prolly my idea might prove useful to developers who are will review this. I had a similar challenge.

the simple way is to comment out this:

```
#category=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
#    Category.objects.filter(id__in=your_profile_instance.category.all()),
#    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
#)
```

lol and then below, after listing the fields add:

```
widgets = {
     'category': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    }
```

yea....

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: and the in the views u can filter like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259091/django-form-only-show-manytomany-objects-from-logged-in-user

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the relation "category" can only be associated from a Profile *instance* (giving the associated categories), not from the class Profile itself. That's why you get the error message.

If you substitute Profile in you example with the actual Profile instance (which I read is what you actually try to achieve) it would work better.

```
category=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    Category.objects.filter(id__in=your_profile_instance.category.all()),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
)
```

or just

```
category=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=your_profile_instance.category.all()),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
)
```

Have I understood your question correctly?

Comment: Only, you don't have access to your_profile_instance when defining the category field as Larry Mai does.