# Django Form: Only show manytomany objects from logged in user

Tags: python, django, django-forms, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

The current problem is that my form shows the logged in user all Portfolios ever created. The form should only show portfolios that the logged-in user created.

Something like this:

```
associated_portfolios manytomany field = ...objects.filter(user=user_id)
```

I'm not sure if this should be implemented in the forms.py or views.py and if so how. I've been going through the django documentation and found 'formfield_for_manytomany' but not sure if this is only meant for admin.

Models.py

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    associated_portfolios = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

Views.py

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreateForm

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        self.fields['associated_portfolios'] = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, using=self.using, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class PortfolioCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ['user', 'name', 'description']    

class PostCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['user', 'title', 'body', 'category', 'associated_portfolios']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a `ModelForm`, the `associated_protfolios` field will be a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)]. This field has a `queryset` attribute [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships)]. We want to modify that attribute.

Django's `CreateView` has a method `get_form`, which in this case will grab your `PostCreateForm`. This is a good spot to filter the field's queryset, since we have access to the user:

```py
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreateForm

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)  # Get the form as usual
        user = self.request.user
        form.fileds['associated_portfolios'].queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=user)
        return form
```

Comment: Really interesting approach. Thanks for the help. Currently getting AttributeError: 'PostCreateForm' object has no attribute 'fileds' - would it be right to try to add the queryset inside of the forms? associated_portfolios = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=...

Comment: Ahh! Just realized 'fileds' was a typo! Talk about tunnel vision. Your solution worked! Thanks a lot! Quick question why use form = super().get_form(*args, **kwargs) and not form = PostCreateForm()

Comment: Glad it worked! In this case, there's no difference (you can look at the docs for CreateView's get_form method and see it just returns an instance of `form_class` if one is given), except that calling `super().get_form()` is more DRY. If you were to change your form class name, you would only need to change it in one spot, rather than two if you used `form = PostCreateForm()`. Also, it's a best practice in cases like this. Sometimes there are other implementation details you might miss if you don't call super.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
self.fields['associated_portfolios'] = Post.objects.filter(associated_portfolios__portfolio__user=request.user)
```

OR

```
user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
self.fields['associated_portfolios'] = user_posts.associated_portfolios.all()
```

read more about M2M relationships querying [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), because I think your problem may be with it.

Also, I'm not sure about your actual data maybe it's right and it gives a correct result as filtering `Portfolio` model against current user to get its objects looks right for me, but anyway double check everything again.

And as a final note, add `related_name` to your model fields so you can use it easily for reverse relations rather than going with Django's default naming, it will be clearer and give a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt at a solution! Unfortunately, no luck with those solutions and ya I've read up and down that M2M Django doc but there's no examples on how to filter the fields.